# Problem related to the table control and the assignment of the value of a parameter to a combo box windev

Tags: sql, combobox, windev

Good morning.
I encounter a weird problem to which I cannot find a solution (at least for the moment).I have a Request for Analysis window. It contains a form composed of three input fields and three Combo box controls with input: **SAI_Datedemande** allowing to inform the date of request for analysis (filled by datesys), **SAI_DateResultat** allowing to inform the date on which the result of the analysis is available, **SAI_ResultatAna** allowing to inform the result of the analysis, a **Combo_NomSoignant** with input allowing to enter the name of the caregiver who requests the analysis linked to the CAREGIVER data file and who refers to its progress two **LASTNAME** AND **FIRST NAME** columns in table form, there is **Combo_Patient** with input linked to the **PATIENT** data file and which functions as **Combo_Patient** that is to say, returns two columns also and **Combo_CodeAna** with input linked to the **TYPEANALYSE** entity which returns only the code name of the analysis, therefore a single column (Ex: TDR).When I request the registration goes through. Note that the recording is done in a data file resulting from a many to several relationship of three data files (**PATIENT**, **TYPEANALYSE**, **CAREGIVERS**). Here is the picture of the window.

[Analysis request window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpR2O.png)

I have another window allowing to display the requests for analyzes. On this window there is a table control (**TABLE_REQ_Select_Analyses**). The table control is linked to a query (**REQ_Select_Analyses**). I wanted to link the table field to the ANALYZE data file (where the recording is done but the result obtained is abnormal, some data is not displayed when I transform the types of column into combo boxes).
Here is my first question:

**1) Please what can cause this display anomaly? Is it because of foreign keys or is my Windev messing around? (I've never had this problem before)**

**Now secondly:**
Here is the code for the **REQ_Select_Analyses** query:

```
SELECT ANALYSES.DateAnalyse AS DateAnalyse, ANALYSES.ResultatAnalyse AS ResultatAnalyse, ANALYSES.DaterResultat AS DaterResultat, ANALYSES.IDPATIENTS AS IDPATIENTS, ANALYSES.IDSOIGNANTS AS IDSOIGNANTS, ANALYSES.IDTYPESANALYSES AS IDTYPESANALYSES, ANALYSES.IDANALYSES AS IDANALYSES, PATIENTS.IDPATIENTS, PATIENTS.NomPatient AS NomPatient, SOIGNANTS.IDSOIGNANTS, SOIGNANTS.NomSoignant AS NomSoignant, TYPEANALYSES.IDTYPESANALYSES, TYPEANALYSES.CodeTypeAnalyse AS CodeTypeAnalyse FROM ANALYSES, PATIENTS, SOIGNANTS, TYPEANALYSES WHERE ANALYSES.IDPATIENTS=PATIENTS.IDPATIENTS AND ANALYSES.IDSOIGNANTS=SOIGNANTS.IDSOIGNANTS AND ANALYSES.IDTYPESANALYSES=TYPEANALYSES.IDTYPESANALYSES
```

And the display works in the table field.

To modify the data when selecting a line, click on a modify button which must open the previous analysis request window and return the information for the selected line in the fields mentioned above, since the table is based on a request when the window opens the fields are not pre-filled to correct this problem I created global variables:

```
gsNomSoignant is string; gsNomPatient is string; gsCodeTypeAna is string; gdDateDemandAna is Date; gdDateResutat is Date; gsResultatAnalyse is string
```

To these variables under the table TABLE_REQ_Select_Analyses at the event selection of a line I assign the data column by column:

```
Open(FEN_Demande_d_analyse,gsNomSoignant,gsNomPatient,gsCodeTypeAna,gdDateDemandAna,gdDateResutat,gsResultatAnalyse); TableDisplay(TABLE_REQ_Select_Analyses,taCurrentSelection)
```

Under the girl window I add parameters:

```
PROCEDURE FEN_Demande_d_analyse(sNomSoignant,sNomPatient,sCodeAna,dDateDemandeAna,dDateResutat,sResultatAna)
```

Under the event at the end of initialization of the window I assign the corresponding information to the fields:

```
FileToScreen(FEN_Demande_d_analyse,ANALYSES); SAI_DateAnalyse=dDateDemandeAna; SAI_DaterResultat=dDateResutat; SAI_ResultatAnalyse=sResultatAna; COMBO_TYPEANALYSES=sCodeAna; COMBO_PATIENTS=sNomPatient; COMBO_SOIGNANTS=sNomSoignant
```

And this is where the problem arises. The input fields receive the information to be assigned very well, but the combo fields do not. I use the properties (..content, ..value, ... etc) a bit of everything but nothing. However, if I assign the information that should normally be assigned to a combo field to an input field, this is displayed very well.

**2) Please what is the cause and how to correct this problem so that the assignments go to normal in the combo fields.**

Thank you for the help that will be granted to me

Answer (score 0):

when you use a "file table" with combo box, be sure to correctly fill the combo box column in the "Content" tab menu.
After that, you can set the data displayed in the "Liaison" tab.

For a classic combo box, same song, fill it with data (use listeAdd if you want to fill it by yourself, or Content tab if you want to fill it with a request).

After that, you can define the "liaison" that will be use with fileToScreen or you can use ListSelectPlus with a ListSearch.

Please take an eye to glien. It allows you to have a value displayed different from the setted value.